# Angular 9 dynamic controls with formarray not working properly

Tags: angular, forms, angular9, dynamic-forms

I am using a formarray to dynamically add or remove multiple fields. And it is working quite well.

But I am having a strange problem. These dynamic form controls are only taking single digit or character at a time.

For ex: For quantity form control  -if I type 8 then it is automatically going to next form control, so I have click again on quantity control and type another digit.

In short, it is taking single or character digit at a time not 3-4 digits like "1234" or a string.

I can't get why this is happening?

Thank you in advance

.ts

```
    purchaseform = this.fb.group({

      vendor_mobile : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      product : this.fb.array([this.addProductGroup()])

    })

    addProductGroup() {
      return this.fb.group({
        product_name : ['', Validators.required ],
        product_quantity : ['', Validators.required],
        product_Buyingprice : ['', Validators.required],
        totalprice : ['']
      })
    }

      get vendor_mobile() {
    return this.purchaseform.get('vendor_mobile')
   }


   get product() {
    return this.purchaseform.get('product') as FormArray;
  }


   get product_name() {
    return this.purchaseform.get('product_name')
   }

   get product_quantity() {
    return this.purchaseform.get('product_quantity')
   }    
   get product_Buyingprice() {
    return this.purchaseform.get('product_Buyingprice')
   }
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="purchaseform"> 

        <h2>Add product details</h2>

            <div formArrayName = "product"  *ngFor="let prod of purchaseform.controls.product?.value; let i = index">       
             <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">

            <h3>Select product</h3>

            <div class="form-group">


            <select class="browser-default custom-select" formControlName = "product_name"  >
                    <option value="" disabled >Select Product </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let prod of product_list" [ngValue]="prod.product_id" > {{prod.name}} </option>
           </select>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">

              <label>product quantity</label>
              <input formControlName="product_quantity" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product quantity">

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">

            <label>product Price</label>
            <input formControlName="product_Buyingprice" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product buying price">
        </div>

        <button type="button" [disabled]="!purchaseform.valid" class="btn btn-primary"  (click) = "addproduct()">Add product</button>  

        <button [disabled] = "i==0" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) = "remove_product(i)">Delete product</button>

      </ng-container>
       </div>

      <button type="button" [disabled]="!purchaseform.valid || clicked " class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looping purchaseform array value use controls.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
<div formArrayName="product" *ngFor="let prod of product?.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <h3>Select product</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="browser-default custom-select" formControlName = "product_name"  >
                    <option value="" disabled >Select Product </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let prod of product_list" [ngValue]="prod.product_id" > {{prod.name}} </option>
           </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>product quantity</label>
                <input formControlName="product_quantity" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product quantity">

          </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label>product Price</label>
                    <input formControlName="product_Buyingprice" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product buying price">
        </div>
                    <button type="button" [disabled]="!purchaseform.valid" class="btn btn-primary"  (click) = "addproduct()">Add product</button> 
                    <button [disabled] = "i==0" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) = "remove_product(i)">Delete product</button>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/anguar-form-issue)

Comment: Thank you. small mistake though